# Linux Socket - Clear the flag set by shutdown() systemcall

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

How to clear the flag set by `shutdown()` system call in Linux socket program?

I want to enable writes to the socket which is right now locked for writes with a `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR)` call.

Comment: `shutdown` isn't just about setting a flag that blocks a specific function of the socket; it shuts down that part of the connection, as the name suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you ask is impossible.

Issuing `shutdown( sockfd, SHUT_WR );`, in fact, forces `FIN` packet to be sent.

Have a look to the TCP state machine:

[image: TCP State Machine]

As you can see, when a `FIN` packet is sent from an active socket (state `ESTABLISHED`) the state `CLOSE_WAIT` is reached, and it is a transition that cannot be *"undone"* in any way.

So it is not a matter of *"removing a flag"*: the socket is set to an irreversible path tha leads to its closure, waiting just for a last `ACK` to complete its "life".